# Choose where the number increments starts in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
dir -exclude "newname_" | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('newname_{0}.pdf' -f $nr++)}
```

This gives me

```
newname_1.pdf, newname_2.pdf, newname_3.pdf
```

etc

but what if I want it to start on another number:

```
newname_174.pdf, newname_175.pdf etc
```

Comment: You just define the number you want to start with in advance ... `$nr = 173`

Comment: Do you have inconsistency to where the number should start? also is this something you want to automate?

Comment: There is a strange behavior of the second file that is created or rather it seems to be picking the last file in the folder and renaming it as nr 2

Comment: $nr=174; dir -exclude "book_vol_2_" | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('book_vol_2_{0}.pdf' -f $nr++)}

Everything is named properly except for the second file which is the last file in the folder. I am not sure why it does this. If I manually rename this second file to book_vol_2_179 (so that it appears last in the folder) and run the code again it works. But not sure why i doesn't do it right the first time and it is always the second file in the folder

Answer (score 1):

Easy! Just declare your counter *before* the rest of your command and initialize it with the value you want to start at:

```bsh
$nr=174
dir -exclude "newname_" | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('newname_{0}.pdf' -f $nr++)}
```

You can do it all in a single line by separating the two expressions with a semicolon

```bsh
$nr=174; dir -exclude "newname_" | %{Rename-Item $_ -NewName ('newname_{0}.pdf' -f $nr++)}
```

Comment: There is a strange behavior of the second file that is created or rather it seems to be picking the last file in the folder and renaming it as nr 2